# Jenkins declarative pipelines: how to always check out latest commit from github, do not schedule a new job if already scheduled?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have some Jenkins jobs which check out multiple github repos before builds; a single build can take an hour or more. We want to schedule new builds if something changes, but currently Jenkins is scheduling way too many builds. We have set up a SCM poll after each 10 minutes and it schedules a new run of the job each 10 minutes, even though there are already 5 runs of the same job waiting in the queue. It looks like it has gone much worse when switching over to git, with svn it was not so bad.

Our desires are humble in my opinion:

1. Do not schedule a new job if one is already sitting in the waiting list.
2. When running a job, always check out the latest commit from all repos, to accommodate all changes.

Is it possible to achieve this with Jenkins declarative pipelines? I tried to solve 2) by a `localBranch: '**'` trick I found in internet, but not sure if it works and maybe it has made 1) worse. A sketch of our pipeline looks like:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'BuildWin6'
    }
    triggers {
        pollSCM '*/10 * * * *'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                dir('production') {
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/main']], extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: '**']], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'b342365f-2641-4fe7-a77d-e4378431434f', url: 'git@github.com:Company/Project']]])
                }
                dir('test-core') {
                    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/main']], extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: '**']], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'b342365f-2641-4fe7-a77d-e4378431434f', url: 'git@github.com:Company/Project-test-core.git']]])
                }
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Maybe disableConcurrentBuilds() is a part of the solution? Is is possible to use (web)hooks  from your SCM instead of polling?

Comment: Our Jenkins is in intranet, so it is not visible to github and must use polling AFAICS.

Comment: The docu of disableConcurrentBuilds() only talks about currently running builds, not about the ones which are sitting in the build queue. To be honest, these are "half-running" while waiting for the build node to become available. But anyway, I do not want to abort any build, I just want to avoid scheduling them in the first place.

Comment: Our Jenkins is also disconnected from the internet but we have an nginx instance that can receive a github webhook and forward it to Jenkins. The builds only start when there's a change, and there is no delay.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question myself. I could not get Jenkins pipeline `triggers` mechanism to do what I wanted, neither `pollSCM` nor `upstream`. Instead I discovered by experimenting with Groovy that it exposes the needed info via `Hudson.instance.queue.getItems()` and `item.getTask().getName()`. The latter seems to report the same build queue lines which appear on screen, e.g. `part of MyJobName #243`, from where I can see if a job is sitting in the build queue.

So, my solution now is to add a separate Jenkins job which runs after each 10 minutes, checks from various repos if there is a new commit, and triggers the needed jobs. This trigger job must run on a specific separate node which does not run any other long jobs, to ensure that it indeed runs each 10 minutes.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'node1'
    }
    triggers {
        cron('*/10 * * * *')
    }
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10', daysToKeepStr: '1'))
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Working') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def text = "";
                    for (job in Hudson.instance.queue.getItems()) {
                        text = text.concat("${job.getTask().getName()}\n")
                    }
                    println "Current build queue:\n${text}"
                    writeFile file: 'jenkins-queue.txt', text: "${text}"
                }
                
                sh '''
set +x
URL1='https://github.com/MyCompany/Project1'
URL2='https://github.com/MyCompany/Project2'
URL3='http://svnrepos/code/Projects/Project3/trunk/Production'
URL4='http://svnrepos/code/Projects/Project4/trunk/Production'

BRANCH1='main'
BRANCH2='main'

HASH1=`git ls-remote $URL1 $BRANCH1 | awk '{print $1}'`
HASH2=`git ls-remote $URL2 $BRANCH2 | awk '{print $1}'`
HASH3=`svn info --show-item last-changed-revision $URL3`
HASH4=`svn info --show-item last-changed-revision $URL4`

LINE="$HASH1 $HASH2 $HASH3 $HASH4"
echo "Repo state: $LINE"

if [ -z "$HASH1" ] || [ -z "$HASH2" ] || [ -z "$HASH3" ] || [ -z "$HASH4" ]; then
    echo "Could not retrieve repo state"
    exit 1
fi

JOBS="MyJobName1 MyJobName2 MyJobName3"

rm -f jenkins-trigger.txt
touch jenkins-trigger.txt

for JOB in $JOBS; do
    touch "$JOB.triggered"

    if fgrep -q "$LINE" "$JOB.triggered"; then
        echo "Job already triggered for this repo state: $JOB"
    else
        if egrep -qw "$JOB" jenkins-queue.txt; then
            echo "Job already in Jenkins build queue, marking as triggered: $JOB"
            echo "$LINE" > "$JOB.triggered"
        else
            echo "Triggering job: $JOB"
            echo "$JOB" >> jenkins-trigger.txt
            echo "$LINE" > "$JOB.triggered"
        fi
    fi
done
                '''
                
                script {
                    def text2 = readFile('jenkins-trigger.txt')
                    def lines = text2.readLines()
                    for (line in lines) {                                            
                        println "Triggering job: ${line}"
                        build(job: "${line}", wait: false)
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

The middle part could be written of course in Groovy as well, I'm sure.

For triggering a cascading job the previous job can do a similar thing in the end:

```
pipeline {
   // ... ...

    post {
        success {
            script {
                def triggerNextJob = true;
                for (job in Hudson.instance.queue.getItems()) {
                    def line = "${job.getTask().getName()}";
                    println "In build queue: ${line}"
                    def pos = line.indexOf("MyNextJobName1");
                    if (pos != -1) {
                        println "Next build already in queue, will not trigger: MyNextJobName1"
                        triggerNextJob = false;
                    }
                }
                if (triggerNextJob) {
                    println "Triggering next job: MyNextJobName1"
                    build(job: "MyNextJobName1", wait: false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```